# FFmpeg change output to specific pixel format?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I am working on an openCV project, I have a stable running variant that is taking input from an HDMI capture card and using FFmpeg to output to a v4L2 loopback device (/dev/video0) my openCV project takes its input from /dev/video0.

The issue comes when I try to use an rtsp feed, the following command works to send the feed to my loopback device:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://@192.168.1.27:552//stream1 -acodec rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

And I am able to view that feed with VLC (on /dev/video0) no problem, however when I feed it to my openCV app, I get the following error:

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
```

When I run `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --all` on both working and non working variants this is what I get:

Working output

```
Format Video Output:
Width/Height      : 1920/1080
Pixel Format      : 'UYVY'
Field             : None
Bytes per Line    : 3840
Size Image        : 4147200
Colorspace        : sRGB
Transfer Function : Default
YCbCr Encoding    : Default
Quantization      : Default
Flags             :
```

Nonfunctional output

```
Format Video Output:
Width/Height      : 1280/720
Pixel Format      : 'YU12'
Field             : None
Bytes per Line    : 1280
Size Image        : 1382400
Colorspace        : sRGB
Transfer Function : Default
YCbCr Encoding    : Default
Quantization      : Default
Flags             :
```

So I am concluding that the pixel format 'YU12' is not compatible with openCV while format 'UYVY' is. If it's possible, how do I set the output of FFmpeg to be in pixel format UYVY when the input is YU12?

Answer (score 23):

Use the [`format`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#format-1) filter or the [`-pix_fmt`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Advanced-Video-options) option. For example we'll use `yuv420p` pixel format!

```sh
# Using the format filter (yuv420p)
ffmpeg -i in_file -filter:v "format=yuv420p" out_file

# Using the 'pix_fmt' option
ffmpeg -i in_file -pix_fmt yuv420p out_file
```

> **[Bonus]** there are plenty of pixel formats available to get a list of them run `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`.

Comment: You can see a list of pixel formats with `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`.

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg `-pix_fmts` will see a list of available pixel formats

Use

```
-pix_fmt rgb24
```

for example and you wont see that deprecated warning anymore